# Differentiate between admin and user login?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am designing a website, which has a login module.. here 3 users/persons (mainly) will be accessing the login page:

1. Superadmin (domain owner)
2. Local admin (under domain owner)
3. Normal user (under local admin)

Where domain owner has rights over local admin & normal user, and local admin has rights over normal user..

Now, how can I differentiate the login type for the above users?

I have tried putting a dropdown, and adding the three members, but I don't feel it looks good.

Any ideas of doing the above scenario?

Comment: You should at membership and roles. [Here's a good tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342061/Understanding-ASP-NET-Roles-and-Membership-A-Begin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normal website these would be handled as roles.

During user creation of later you assign roles to users.

Your login page only needs a user to enter username and password.

You could easily persist the user-role relationship in a database.

Asp.net has first class support for roles in the  [`RoleProviders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You can use roles to authorize which users have access to what parts of the website.

Refer: [Creating and Managing Roles](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have another [presumably SQL] table for access rights/levels/permissions. For the most basic implementation, have the 3 options in an `enum`, and `update` each `user` with the user level `enum`.